# Not all my text is showing for my input fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a few input filed on my site however the labels are not fully displayed. When I inspect the page there is more space to the label on the left side. The text in the blue isn't showing up even though in my code it is. I am not sure why all me texts aren't showing? Below I will provide the code and what I see.

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManagerComment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="row right">
                <input value="Meeting Scheduled" class="btn btn-link  nopadding fontsemilabel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("MeetingSch", "Strategy", new {id = Model.StrategyId})'" />
            </div>
            <div class="row right">
                <input value="Need to schedule visit" class="btn btn-link nopadding fontsemilabel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SchVisit", "Strategy", new {id = Model.StrategyId})'" />
            </div>
            <div class="row right">
                <input value="Need to schedule eMeeting" class="btn btn-link nopadding fontsemilabel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ScheMeet", "Strategy", new {id = Model.StrategyId})'" />
            </div>
            <div class="row right">
                <input value="No action at this time, followup planned" class="btn btn-link nopadding fontsemilabel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("NoAct", "Strategy", new {id = Model.StrategyId})'" />
            </div>
            <div class="row right">
                <input value="Samples Requested" class="btn btn-link nopadding fontsemilabel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SampReq", "Strategy", new {id = Model.StrategyId})'" />
            </div>
            <div class="row right">
                <input value="Evaluating Samples" class="btn btn-link nopadding fontsemilabel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("EvalSamp", "Strategy", new {id = Model.StrategyId})'" />
            </div>
            <div class="row right">
                <input value="Need to Confirm CEM location" class="btn btn-link nopadding fontsemilabel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ConfirmCEM", "Strategy", new {id = Model.StrategyId})'" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ManagerComment, 100, 50, new { id = "questionInput", maxlength = 1000, style = "width: 100%; max-width: 100%" })
            <div id="charsLeft"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <p style="white-space: pre-line">
                    <input value="New Update" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Update", "Strategy", new {id = Model.StrategyId})'" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

CSS below:

```
.right {
    text-align: right;
}

textarea {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
}

.fontsemilabel {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

.nopadding {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I think this is more of a CSS issue than code. It looks like you have bootstrap classes. What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to check. I think I am using Bootstrap 4.1.3? I will add the corresponding CSS to the code above.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not aware of CSS then

simply apply table with correspondent data like

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
 <input value="Meeting Scheduled" class="btn btn-link  nopadding fontsemilabel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("MeetingSch", "Strategy", new {id = Model.StrategyId})'" />
</td>
<td>
<input value="Need to Confirm CEM location" class="btn btn-link nopadding fontsemilabel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ConfirmCEM", "Strategy", new {id = Model.StrategyId})'" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

like...